# Not able to connect replica set of mongo DB in mongo-kafka source connect

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, mongodb-kafka-connector

Am using mongo kafka source connector v1.6.. Am trying to connect it replica set of mongo db
I have connection uri like this

> mongodb://:@instance1:27017,instance2:27017,instance3:27017/?authSource=test&replicaSet=replicaset&ssl=true

the  error am getting is

> unable to connect server

... username and password is crct and also connectivity to DB also open
can u please tell what am doing wrong

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB services?

Comment: Are you sure about `authSource=test`? Typically users are created in `admin` database?

Comment: Try testing that connection string with the mongo shell or compass.

Comment: Have tried with authSource=admin still didn't work

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you solved this? @karthik